# algorithm to find a number in which product of number of 4 & 7 is maximum in given range

Tags: algorithm

I am stuck in a question in which lower bound `L` and Upper bound `U` is given.
Now suppose in the decimal representation of integer `X` digit 4 appears `A` times and digit 7 appears `B` times.
Problem is to find `X` which has maximum value of `A*B` for `L<=X<=U`.
Is there any efficient algorithm to solve it?

Comment: Probably. How far were you able to get with your attempts?

Comment: @AHungerArtist I am not able to design any feasible algorithm. Since constraints to L&U can go upto 10^18, i don't think that an algorithm checking each and every number between L and R will be feasible. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, the following should work:

- Assume all numbers have the same number of digits (if e.g. **L** has less digits than **U**, we can just fill in the beginning with 0 s).
- Let **Z** = **U** - **L**.
- Now we go from the first (/highest/leftmost) digit to the last one. If we are looking at the **i** th digit, let **L**(i), **U**(i), **Z**(i) and **X**(i) be the corresponding digit.

  - for all leading **Z**(i) which are 0, we set **X**(i) = **L**(i) (we don't have a choice).
  - For the first not 0 **Z**(i) check: is there a 4 or a 7 in the interval [**L**(i), **U**(i)-1]? If yes let **X**(i) be that 4 or 7 otherwise let **X**(i) = **U**(i)-1.
  - Now fill up the rest of **X** with 4s and 7s such that you choose a 4 if you have assigned more 7s so far and vice versa.

---

Maybe an example can help in understanding this:

Given **U** = 5000 and **L** = 4900.

Now **Z** = 0100.

From the algorithm we set

- **X**(1) = **L**(1) = 4 (we have no choice)
- **X**(2) = **U**(2)-1 = 9 (the first non 0 digit in **Z**)
- **X**(3) = 7 (we already had a 4)
- **X**(4) = 4 (can be chosen arbitrarily)

Leading to **X** = 4974 with an objective of 2*1=2

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have the algorithm thought out already. 
Just break it down piece by piece and solve each part. I usually write something like you did there with comments and then break those down until they are at a reasonable bite size to write code for.

When you have it working, if needed, you can optimize it.

Comment: Will you please explain it a little more. With an example if possible.

Comment: This answer is so general as to have no value.