# programming puzzle

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [algorithm to find a number in which product of number of 4 & 7 is maximum in given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898626/algorithm-to-find-a-number-in-which-product-of-number-of-4-7-is-maximum-in-giv)

Let `F4(X)` be the number of digits 4 in the decimal representation of X, and `F7(X)` be the number of digits 7 in the decimal representation of X. For example,

```
F4(456) = 1, F4(444) = 3, F7(1) = 0, F7(747) = 2.
```

how the below thing can be solved?

find max of `{F4(X) ∙ F7(X) : L ≤ X ≤ R}`

```
1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ 10^18
```

what is the fastest algorithm for solving this?

1.one can try brute force by finding all numbers between L and R and finding the max product but such an approach will easily time out.

Comment: You can figure this out in your head faster than you can put the algorithm into words. Did you try?

Comment: Exactly this question was asked yesterday, but I can't find a link

Comment: algorithm provided in the link is certainly  wrong.
just try it for a simple case when
left = 22 and right = 49.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an homework, I will only give you suggestions in form of questions:

- How many digits are there in a number between 1 and 10^18?
- Can a digit be a 7 and a 4 simultaneously?

Comment: Sometimes it can, if the number is sneaky enough...